How to decode KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT from lParam using koffi in Node.js?
I'm trying to convert a C++ keyboard hook program to Node.js using the koffi library. In C++, I would typically cast the lParam parameter to a KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT pointer like this:
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *pKeyBoard = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;

Here’s the full c++
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

// Global variable to store the hook handle
HHOOK hKeyboardHook;

// Callback function for handling keyboard events
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::cout << nCode << std::endl;
    std::cout << wParam << std::endl;
    std::cout << lParam << std::endl;
    if (nCode >= 0)
    { // The keyboard message is being processed
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        { // A key was pressed down
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *pKeyBoard = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
            DWORD vkCode = pKeyBoard->vkCode;
            std::cout << "Key pressed: " << vkCode << std::endl;

            // If the ESC key is pressed, exit the application
            if (vkCode == VK_ESCAPE)
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hKeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    // Set a global keyboard hook
    hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, NULL, 0);

    if (hKeyboardHook == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to install hook!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Hook installed successfully!" << std::endl;

    // Message loop
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    // Unhook when no longer needed
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyboardHook);

    return 0;
}

This allows me to access the virtual key code (and other data) from the KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT structure.
How can I achieve the same in Node.js using koffi? Below is my current code:
import koffi from "koffi"
import * as D from "win32-def/def"

const HHOOK = koffi.pointer("HHOOK", koffi.opaque())
const HINSTANCE = koffi.pointer("HINSTANCE", D.INT)

const LRESULT = koffi.alias("LRESULT", D.LONG_PTR)
const WPARAM = koffi.alias("WPARAM", D.ULONG_PTR)
const LPARAM = koffi.alias("LPARAM", D.LONG_PTR)

const KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT = koffi.struct("KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT", {
  vkCode: "DWORD",
  scanCode: "DWORD",
  flags: "DWORD",
  time: "DWORD",
  dwExtraInfo: "ULONG_PTR",
})
export const HOOKPROC = koffi.proto("HOOKPROC", "LRESULT", ["int", "WPARAM", "LPARAM"])

export const SetWindowsHookExA = user32.func("SetWindowsHookExA", "HHOOK", [D.INT, koffi.pointer(HOOKPROC), HINSTANCE, "DWORD"])

const WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13

export const installMouseHook = () => {
  if (!hHook) {
    const hInstance = GetModuleHandle(null)
    hHook = SetWindowsHookExA(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, onHookProc, null, 0)
    if (!hHook) {
      throw new Error("Failed to install keyboard hook")
    }
    console.log("Keyboard hook installed.")
  }
}

// Hook callback function
const onHookProc = koffi.register((nCode, wParam, lParam) => {
  console.log(nCode, wParam, lParam)

  let kb = koffi.decode(lParam, "KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT") // <====not work
  let kb1= koffi.as(lParam, "KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT") //<====not work

  return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam)
}, koffi.pointer(HOOKPROC))

I tried using koffi.decode and koffi.as, but I wasn't able to correctly convert the lParam to access the KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT structure in Node.js.
Any guidance would be appreciated!

Since the code doesn't attempt to reject input there's no reason to install a costly hook. Use Raw Input for monitoring purposes.

@IInspectable What I want to achieve is that when the user presses the 'A' key, the program detects it, intercepts the input, and changes it to the 'B' key instead. This is a form of keyboard mapping functionality.

After numerous attempts, I finally found the solution.
const LPARAM = koffi.pointer("LPARAM", D.LPARAM)

let info = koffi.decode(lParam, "KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT")
console.log(`Key pressed: ${JSON.stringify(info)}`)
//Key pressed: {"vkCode":65,"scanCode":30,"flags":128,"time":85736828,"dwExtraInfo":0}



